# Asterisk line fluctuation issue

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way in which we can know when an asterisk PRI line fluctuates? Can we get a trigger that something has gone wrong?

This is creating a problem because sometimes the Asterisk server needs to be restarted and I don't know that something has gone wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by fluctuates?  I take it if just restarting asterisk is clearing your condition that it's not an alarm on the actual layer 1 link but something in the upper level protocols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more sophisticated things you could do with log settings, and parsing the logs, but you could also just brute force it.

Write a script that you run in cron that calls `asterisk -rx 'pri show spans'` and parse the output and take whatever action you deem necessary.

Comment: Thanks that will do my job.